# Why .valid() always returns TRUE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, razor

I know that there were loads and loads questions like this one, but none of them really helped.

I have two forms on one page (some fields are shared), only one form is going to be submitted at a time. I thought that it's because the some fields are shared, but I removed 2nd form completely from the page and the error still existed.

I'm implementing custom validator, but when I call .valid() it always returns TRUE, even tho rules are stating otherwise.

Currently I have validator only for the 1st form (I didn't move on, because it failed).

```
$('#driver-form').validate({
rules:{
    FirstName: {
        required:true,
        minlength: 2,
    },
    LastName: {
        required:true,
        minlength: 2,
    },
    Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    PhoneNum: {
        required: true,
        exactlength: 11,
    },        
    Password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        symbol: true
    }
},messages:{
    Firstname: {
        required: "Please enter your firstname",
        minlength: "Firstname should contain more that 2 characters"
    },
    LastName: {
        required: "Please enter your lastname",
        minlength: "Lastname should contain more that 2 characters"
    },
}});
```

Here is the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", @id = "driver-form" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsGarage, new { @class = "_HdnIsGarage" })

    <div class="registration-form" id="driver-registration-form">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div>
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName).HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "First Name" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName).HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Last Name" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Email).HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "E-mail", @type = "e-mail" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNum).HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Phone Number" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Password).HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Password", @type = "password" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @*@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword).Name("pw").HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Password" }))*@
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("Register").Content("Register").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", onclick = "Javascript:driverRegister()" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here jQuery that gets called when click 'Register':

```
        function driverRegister() {
        debugger;
        var test1 = $('#driver-form')
        var test = $('#driver-registration-form input');
        alert(test.valid())
        if (test.valid() == true) {
            $('#driver-form').submit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using validate.unobtrusive too? If so, try `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#driver-form'))` before calling `.valid()`.

Comment: For starters assuming you are using JQuery validation plugin, `.valid()` function validates a form not an input field. - [Check here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

Comment: @Stuart, I have user and js complained about .parse,

NikhilNanjappa, I am validating input in different form and it works perfectly

Comment: Besides, I have tried validating both, input AND a form itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, wrapping validate function with $(document).ready(function () {});
seems to solve the issue. Thanks everyone who helped :)